# Transportation models in economics

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, welfare-economics, economic-measurement

How would one go about modelling the effectiveness of public transportation? More specifically how does one go about comparing two transit systems in terms of their ability to move a larger numbers of people and how fast they move them.

Comment: There are notions of flow networks and routing games in the algorithmic game theory literature. I would start there.